# trying to set friendly URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to configure a friendly URL system for my website and due to i'm new in these tools, I was testing at the first time on my client localhost.

The fact is I want to convert this URL: 
http://laventanaindiscretadiego.url.ph/page/index.inc.php?lang=en_EN
into this other one
http://laventanaindiscretadiego.com/main

For that i'm using a .htaccess file and i'm using RewriteRule as i show here

```
RewriteRule ^/laventana/page/main$ /laventana/page/index.inc.php?lang=$1
```

after I apply changes on my .htaccess and i save everything, nothing happens and the url is not rewrited.

As an extra information, httpd.conf was already eddited removing the coment for the next lane:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I also checked that AllowOverride was in the option All as you can see:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I also checked that the document root was the correct, in my case:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

The last thing i could say about, it's that the .htaccess document is in the root folder (htdocs) so it makes sense and i've tested it before with a simple redirection like in this example

```
Redirect /laventana/page/index.inc.php?lang=$1 http://www.disney.com
```

The redirect is stupid but i wanted to test the .htaccess was working.

Have anybody any clue of what is happening me and/or if I have any mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: It makes little sense to append `$1` to the target of your internal rewrite, if your pattern does not actually _capture_ any value that could be put in there. And what URL are you now actually calling from your browser? (And your `Redirect` does not make sense either, because that directive also only looks at [part of] the requested URL path, and not the query string as well.)

Comment: Also what is `/laventana` since that is not part of your URL?

Comment: what i wanted is to remake the URL trying to avoid that the user knows where are my page files (actually without friendly URL, you knows all the HTML files are under /page. About the redirect, it was as part of checking the .htaccess was working

Comment: about /laventana, the full URL is http://la-ventana/laventana/page/index.inc.php?lang=en_EN

Comment: I've just found the problem. I was not understanding the function of this tool. Thanks anyway